# EmbeddedKafkaRule have no brokerListProperty method

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I'm trying to figure out Spring Kafka. While following reference I found error in [this example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#kafka-testing-junit4-class-rule). There is no `brokerListProperty()` method in `EmbeddedKafkaRule` class. How should I refactor the code to make it work?

Code from link above:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyApplicationTests {

    @ClassRule
    public static EmbeddedKafkaRule broker = new EmbeddedKafkaRule(1,
        false, "someTopic")
            .brokerListProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers");
    }

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Together with the `@SpringBootTest` consider to use an `@EmbeddedKafka` instead. 
That one has a property like:

```
/**
 * The property name to set with the bootstrap server addresses instead of the default
 * {@value org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker#SPRING_EMBEDDED_KAFKA_BROKERS}.
 * @return the property name.
 * @since 2.3
 * @see org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker#brokerListProperty(String)
 */
String bootstrapServersProperty() default "";
```

The goal for  an `EmbeddedKafkaRule`, when we don't use Spring in tests at all. 
And I agree that we are missing a propagation property from that `EmbeddedKafkaRule` into a `brokerListProperty()`. Please, feel free to raise a GH issue and contribute a fix on the matter.

Meanwhile you can workaround it like this:

```
@ClassRule
public static EmbeddedKafkaRule broker = new EmbeddedKafkaRule(1, false, "someTopic");

@BeforeAll
pubic static void setup() {
    broker.getEmbeddedKafka().brokerListProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers");
}
```

Comment: I've looked into ```@EmbeddedKafka``` [example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#embedded-kafka-annotation) and once again I had issue with running the code. At the line with ```return new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(props);``` I'm getting error stating that ```KafkaStreamsConfiguration``` constructor should take no argument instead of passed props.

Comment: That's also bug, but already a sample one in that doc. You should rename that `KafkaStreamsConfiguration` `@Configuration` class and really import a `org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaStreamsConfiguration` for that proper bean definition.

Answer (score 1):

You can add brokerListProperty like that using `KafkaTestUtils`

```
    @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    // set up the Kafka producer properties
    Map<String, Object> senderProperties =
        KafkaTestUtils.senderProps(
            broker.getEmbeddedKafka().getBrokersAsString());
  }
```

And you can follow this [tutorial](https://codenotfound.com/spring-kafka-embedded-unit-test-example.html) it seems pretty correct.

Comment: I've seen a bit of that tutorial while Googling this topic and my issue with it is that is seems to be a bit outdated. There are many deprecated functions/classes in the code and I'm having trouble running most of the code from GitHub repo linked below it.

Comment: Ok. Managed to make spring-kafka-unit-test-classrule work. Good starting point. Thank you.